# Require Password if Checkbox checked, web services.. c#

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a c# web application that communicates with a web service, the front-end application takes a unique number(staff number), month, and year from the user and retrieve payslip information from the database, generate a pdf file and dumps the employee information on the pdf file.

The pdf file is password protected, when you open the pdf file the password you provide is compared to one of the fields in the database.

**Now my problem is**: if you access the application as an administrator you can download payslips for other employees.

Now I have to add a checkbox which gives the administrator the option to tell the downloaded pdf file whether to require password or not.

If the checkbox is checked the pdf file must require password else password must not be required, am stark on this part and I don't know how to go about in adding this functionality.

Comment: Could you post some code?? Its kinda vague question for me.. !!!

Comment: I currently have no code on this, I've added the checkbox on my application and now I have to tell my application that when the checkbox is checked the pdf file must require password

Comment: Then save the checkbox's value with the row in the database?

Comment: I don't have permission to add fields on the database,I can only select